# face tracking or "dynamic recognition"

Tags: computer-vision, video-processing, face-detection, face-recognition

What is a best approach for face detection/tracking considering following scenario:

when person enters in scene/frame it should be detected and recognized in every next frame until he/she leaves the scene.

also should be able to do this for multiple users at once.

I have experience with viola jones detection, and fisher face recognition. But I've used ff recognition only for previously prepared learning set, and now I need something for any user that enters the scene..

Answer (score 1):

I am also interested in different solutions. 
I used opencv face detection for multiple faces and the rekognition api (http://rekognition.com) and pushed the faces and retrained the dataset frequently. Light-weighted from our side, but I am sure there are more robust solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [VideoSurveillance](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoSurveillance)? Also known as OpenCV blob tracker.
It's a motion-based tracker with across frames data association(1) and if you want to replace motion with face detection, you must adjust the code by replacing the foreground mask with detection responses. This approach is called track-by-detect in the literature.

(1) "Appearance Models for Occlusion Handling", Andrew Senior et al.